# How to install delete-project plugin in gerrit?

Tags: java, python, build, gerrit

I want to install delete-project plugin to my gerrit server.
As per the latest version, I should clone it from google source and use buck build.

I cloned it and my buck is also ready.

What are the steps to be followed to build the delete project plugin and add it to my gerrit server.

I tried

```
buck build .
```

in the cloned source of delete-project. But, I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gerrit/buck/src/com/facebook/buck/parser/buck.py", line 872, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/gerrit/buck/src/com/facebook/buck/parser/buck.py", line 867, in main
    buildFileProcessor.process(build_file.rstrip())
  File "/home/gerrit/buck/src/com/facebook/buck/parser/buck.py", line 800, in process
    build_env['BUILD_FILE_SYMBOL_TABLE'])
  File "/home/gerrit/delete-project/././BUCK", line 1, in <module>
    gerrit_plugin(
NameError: name 'gerrit_plugin' is not defined
BUILD FAILED: Parse error for BUCK file ././BUCK: End of input at line 1 column 1
```

Please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to install delete-project plugin after following this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/hbBc2TUhl7s

and then install according to:

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-plugin-install.html

P.S. I build the jar following the below steps:

1. git clone --recursive https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
2. cd gerrit
3. git clone --recursive https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/delete-project
4. buck build delete-project:delete-project

You should then find the delete-project.jar in buck-out/gen/delete-project/delete-project.jar

Comment: Whenever i run `buck build delete-project:delete-project` i get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py` any idea why? I have the subprocess.py lib

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Are you using Arch Linux? That error occurs because the system's `/usr/bin/python` is Python 3, not Python 2. What you can do is create a directory like `~/bin`, symlink Python 2 into it (`ln -s /usr/bin/python2 ~/bin/python`), and then run buck with `PATH="~/bin:$PATH" buck ...`

Comment: @Xiao-LongChen using ubuntu server 14.04 and `/usr/bin/python --version` gives Python 2.7.6

Comment: Would you mind posting the full build log? The `subprocess` module might be failing because it's trying to run a program that doesn't exist.

Comment: Add `--recursive` option to `git clone` in Step 1 if you want to install one of the plugins included by default in gerrit repository. It'll download all the submodules. Please also note that above steps aren't sufficient when you installed gerrit from `*.war` file. In that case do above steps as a side project, build plugin `*.jar` files and copy them to your production gerrit.

Answer (score 14):

1. Download the `delete-project.jar` from the build that matches your Gerrit version on https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com
2. Copy it to `gerrit/plugins` directory.
3. Restart Gerrit.

Comment: Select the Plugins-stable-2.xx tab matching your Gerrit version to find the correct plugin-delete-project build job.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to successfully build delete-project plugin with a slight modification on @DavidCheung answer:

1. git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
2. cd gerrit/plugins
3. git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/delete-project
4. buck build delete-project:delete-project

You should then find the delete-project.jar in ../buck-out/gen/delete-project/delete-project.jar

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the answers above, maybe due to having a new version of Gerrit (2.11.2).  The steps in [this document](http://review.cyanogenmod.org/Documentation/dev-buck.html) all worked for me, with one addition - you need to add the --recursive flag when you clone the Gerrit source code so that it includes the source for the standard plugins:

```
git clone --recursive https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
```

Also, make sure to check out the correct Git branch for your Gerrit version,e.g.

```
git fetch origin stable-2.11:stable-2.11
git checkout stable-2.11
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to build a `delete-project.jar` for gerrit 3.x.

1. Install [bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.0.0/install.html).
2. Download gerrit source code with `git clone --recursive https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit`
3. `cd gerrit`
4. `bazel build plugins/delete-project:delete-project`

The last step will generate `bazel-bin/plugins/delete-project/delete-project.jar` which then can be installed as described in the [official documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-plugin-install.html).