# SSH/HTTP/Anonymous HTTP Clone URL not visible in Gerrit 2.12.2

Tags: git, ssh, clone, gerrit

I just installed the Gerrit code review system release 2.12.2. I'm managing the authentication to the web interface via LDAP. Once I logged in as the Administrator, I created a project called "testProject". I'm unable to see the SSH/Anonymous HTTP/HTTP clone URLs on the project page in the GUI (see below). The documentation says that if download.scheme is left unspecified in the config, SSH/Anonymous HTTP/HTTP download methods will be the default schemes. Also, I'm unable to clone projects via a URL I created, assuming the format that gerrit would use (ssh://user@localhost:29418/testProject), although my ssh key is added (and I am able to issue commands such as gerrit ls-projects). Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. My config is attached below the image

[image]

```
    [gerrit]
        basePath = git
        canonicalWebUrl = http://<url>:9001/
    [database]
        type = H2
        database = db/ReviewDB
    [index]
        type = LUCENE
    [auth]
        type = LDAP
    [ldap]
        <some LDAP stuff>
    [sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
    [container]
        user = gerrit
        javaHome = <JAVA_HOME>
    [sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
    [httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:9001/
    [cache]
        directory = cache
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has to do with not installing the download-commands plugin for Gerrit. During initialization Gerrit prompts the user to install plugins. If the user says no (or if the installation is performed in --batch mode), the plugins will not be installed.

Here is the reference ticket opened against Gerrit

https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?can=2&q=4029&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Milestone%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary&id=4029

To avoid reinstallation to download/install the plugins, one can:
1. Obtain the pre-built plugins The plugins for the master branch are at

https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/gerritcodereview-plugins/plugins/master/

2. Plugins obtained from Step 1 are incompatible with any other branch but the master. To manually build the plugins, one has to clone the required source branch and install with Buck

[How to install delete-project plugin in gerrit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254291/how-to-install-delete-project-plugin-in-gerrit) 
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/dev-buck.html

3. Once the *.jar files of the plugins are obtained (either by step 1 or step 2), they can be copied over to $gerrit_site/site/plugins/ either manually or by remote plugin install

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-plugin-install.html

Comment: I already have download-commands plugin installed , but I am unble to see anonymous url and unable to clone using http. I have upgraded gerrit from version 2.11.7 to 2.14.2...any idea why I am facing this issue?

Comment: Have you enabled the requisite download types in your gerrit config ? https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/download-commands/+doc/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/about.md