# How to clone a Gerrit Code Review repository to a local repository

Tags: gerrit

I have installed Gerrit Code Review. Everything is working fine but in the documentation it is unclear how to clone a repository to local directory.

Using Gerrit admin interface I created a new project. How do I know what URL to use? Does Gerrit support https access to repositories?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Gerrit Web UI
2. Go to the "Projects > List" menu item
3. Find your project (use the "Filter" field if needed)
4. Click on the project name
5. Go to the "General" tab
6. See the "git clone" command on the top of the page
7. Choose if you want to clone via "http" or "ssh"
8. Copy the "git clone" command clicking on the right icon
9. Paste/execute the "git clone" command

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this issue is related to [SSH/HTTP/Anonymous HTTP Clone URL not visible in Gerrit 2.12.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342703/ssh-http-anonymous-http-clone-url-not-visible-in-gerrit-2-12-2)

I installed in batch mode without plugins. In that case git clone is not there.